# Angular: how to call router.navigate() relative to target route in a RouteGuard?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-route-guards

I have an existing project developed with Angular 4. I need to control the access to a particular route based on user-rights. The simplified route configuration looks like this:

```
[
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/myApp/home(secondary:xyz)', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'myApp'
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', ... },
        ...
        { path: 'product'
          children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'categoryA', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'categoryA', component: CategoryAComponent, canActivate: [CategoryACanActivateGuard]},
            { path: 'categoryB', component: CategoryBComponent},
            ...
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Now, I want to control the access to `www.myWeb.com/myApp/product/categoryA`. If the user doesn't have enough permission, he/she will be redirected to `... /product/CategoryB`. I have written a `CanActivate` RouteGuard to do this, the guard class looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MyService } from '... my-service.service';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryACanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private myService: MyService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.myService.checkPermission()
            .then(result => {
                if (!result.hasAccess) {
                    //redirect here

                    this.router.navigate(['./myApp/product/categoryB']); 
                    //works, but I want to remove hardcoding 'myApp'

                    //this.router.navigate(['../../categoryB']);
                    //doesn't work, redirects to home page

                    //this.router.navigate(['./categoryB'], { relativeTo: this.route});
                    //do not have this.route object. Injecting Activated route in the constructor did not solve the problem

                }
                return result.hasAccess;
            });
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I want redirect relative to the target route like the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['/product/categoryB'], { relativeTo: <route-of-categoryA>});
// or 
this.router.navigate(['/categoryB'], { relativeTo: <route-of-categoryA>});
```

Unfortunately, `relativeTo` accepts only `ActivatedRoute` objects and all I have is `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and `RouterStateSnapshot`. Is there a way to navigate relative to the target route (in this case *categoryA*)? Any help will be really appreciated.

**Note:**

- I can not change the route configuration other than adding some route-guards.
- I am not looking looking for `this.router.navigateByUrl` using `state.url`. I want to use `router.navigate([...], { relativeTo: this-is-what-need})`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out, constructor injected `ActivatedRoute` works differently in *RouteGuard* compare to other places like a *Component*.

In a component, `ActivatedRoute` object points to the route that activated that component. For example, in the `CategoryAComponent` class, the following code will navigate to *CategoryB*:

```
this.router.navigate([ '../CategoryB' ], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

But, the same code above will not work in a `RouteGuard` class added to the *CategoryA* route configuration. In my test, I have found that the constructor injected `ActivatedRoute` object points to the root route. On the other hand, `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` object (passed in as a parameter in the *canActivate* function) points to the target route (in my case *categoryA*). However, we cannot pass this `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` object in `this.router.navigate(...)` function.

I couldn't find a better way to solve this problem, but the following code works for me:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.myService.checkPermission()
        .then(result => {
            if (!result.hasAccess) {
                //redirect here

                let redirectTo = route.pathFromRoot
                    .filter(p => p !== route && p.url !== null && p.url.length > 0)
                    .reduce((arr, p) => arr.concat(p.url.map(u => u.path)), new Array<string>());

                this.router.navigate(redirectTo.concat('categoryB'), { relativeTo: this.route });
            }
            return result.hasAccess;
        });
}
```

Comment: Had the same question. This solution is cumbersome, but it works! Thanks.

Comment: please don't use `router.navigate` in guards. You have the option to return a `UrlTree` in case you want to navigate to a different route.

Comment: state.url is that current path, that is builded for redirectTo. the problem is, when I use such method inside the resolver, it triggers again, cos this navigation is not relative

Answer (score 9):

May I offer you a leaner solution:

```
import {
  CanActivateFn,
  UrlTree,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  createUrlTreeFromSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
```

```
const canActivate: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): true | UrlTree {
  const urlTree = createUrlTreeFromSnapshot(route, ['categoryB']);
  return result.hasAccess || urlTree;
}
```

With this solution you have a possiblity of settings all other props you might need - named outlets navigation, query params, fragments very easily...

[createUrlTreeFromSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/createUrlTreeFromSnapshot)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new [createUrlTreeFromSnapshot()](https://angular.io/api/router/createUrlTreeFromSnapshot) function from Angular 14, like this:

```
const urlTree = createUrlTreeFromSnapshot(routeSnapshot, ['../categoryB']);
this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
```